# I have to replace multiple blanks in a string with a single blank in C

Tags: c, duplicates, char, c-strings, function-definition

This is the code that I came up with:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void delit(char *s, int i) {
  int n = 0;
  for (int j = i; j < strlen(s) - 1; j++) {
    s[j] = s[j + 1];
  }
  printf("%s", s);
}

int main() {
  char s[100];
  printf("gimme string with less than 100 chars");
  gets(s);
  int l = strlen(s);
  for (int i = 0; i <= l - 2; i++) {
    if (s[i] == s[i + 1] && s[i] == ' ') {
    delit(char *s, int i);
    }
  }
  printf("after processing %s", s);
}
```

This is not working and showing 2 errors :

> //too few arguments to function 'delit'{delit(char *s, int i);}

> //ction 'main':tempCodeRunnerFile.c:20:16: error: expected expression before 'char'{delit(char *s, int i);}

Please advise.

Comment: `{delit(char *s, int i);}` this is not how you call a function in C. Just pass the variables, not their types: `{delit(s, i);}`

Comment: You put the types in your function call, you only put those in when defining the function, `delit(s,i)`

Comment: Never ***ever** use `gets`! [It's so dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used) that is has been removed from the C language. Use e.g. [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead.

Comment: @Samuel Ok I fixed it it's working but only for two spaces. For eg with 3 blanks it returns 2 blanks not one??

Comment: @yano Ok I fixed it it's working but only for two spaces. For eg with 3 blanks it returns 2 blanks not one??

Comment: The standard C functions like `printf` and `strlen` are really no different from your own functions. You know how to call them. So you should also know how to call your own function. Was it a copy-paste typo? Or do you really don't know how to call functions?

Comment: glorytothe12suns, NMDV, yet "WHy ... downvoting?"  Poorly formatted code, slang, using `gets()`, "This is not working" is vague. lack of a clear quesiton, asking for [more debug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68987228/i-have-to-replace-multiple-blanks-in-a-string-with-a-single-blank-in-c#comment121924359_68987228) after answring the question all attact DVs.  Review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  On the plus side, good to post the exact error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is your attempt to call the function `delit(char *s, int i)`.  Inside of main() you call the function using `delit(char *s, int i)`.  You don't need to put the types in the function call, so it should just be `delit(s, i)`.

That should make your code compile.

To handle the multiple spaces you could change your loop in main to only advance if the characters are NOT both spaces:

```
for (int i=0;i<=l-1;)
{
    if (s[i]==s[i+1] && s[i]==' ')
    {
        delit(s,i);
    }else{
        i++;
    }            
}
```

Comment: Fixed it. It now works. But only for 2 spaces. For eg if there are three spaces, it returns 2 (and not 1), Thanlks

Comment: @glorytothe12suns See my edit for the multiple spaces fix

Comment: @glorytothe12suns Input `"x  y\n"` --> `"x yy"`,  `"x  \n"` --> apparent infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

This function is incorrect.

```
void delit(char *s, int i) {
  int n = 0;
  for (int j = i; j < strlen(s) - 1; j++) {
    s[j] = s[j + 1];
  }
  printf("%s", s);
}
```

Let's assume that the passed string is `"  A"`. The length of the string is equal to 3, It is stored as a character array `{ ' ', ' ', 'A', '\0' }`.

So the loop will look like

```
  for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
```

and after the loop you will get the string `{ ' ', 'A', 'A', '\0' }` instead of the correct string `{ ' ', 'A', '\0' }`.

Also, it is inefficient to move all characters to the left after it finds a duplicate space character.

Within main this record

```
delit(char *s, int i);
```

is an invalid function declaration with an absent return type instead of a function call.

Also the function [`gets` is unsafe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-dangerous-why-should-it-not-be-used) and is not supported by the C Standard. Instead, use the function `fgets`.

I would define the function `delit` the following way as shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char * delit( char *s, char c )
{
    if ( c != '\0' )
    {
        for ( char *p = s, *q = s; *p++; )
        {
            if ( *p != c || *( p - 1 ) != c )
            {
                if ( ++q != p ) *q = *p;
            }
        }
    }       
    
    return s;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char s[] = "Hello     world!";
    
    printf( "\"%s\"\n", s );
    printf( "\"%s\"\n", delit( s, ' ' ) );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
"Hello     world!"
"Hello world!"
```